# How can I impliment Payeezy Recurring base payment in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, payeezy

I want to integrate recurring payment using Payeezy in my iOS app.

I have integrated one time payment successfully and it is working fine.

how can I achieve this?

I have refered this [link](https://developer.payeezy.com/payeezy-api/apis/post/transactions/%7Bid%7D-1)

Thank you

Comment: Here we can see the view giude pdf and follow the steps...        https://developer.payeezy.com/select-your-integration-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a product manager on the Payeezy team at First Data.

Payeezy APIs, as on date, does not support the initiation of recurring plans managed within Payeezy Gateway. Merchants managing their own recurring plans can pass the data through the API by utilizing the Recurring Indicator.  To utilize the Recurring Indicator you will need to use the “eci_indicator” field and set it to “2”. For example, here is a purchase transaction payload that uses the eci_indicator to denote a recurring payment.

```
{
  "merchant_ref": "Astonishing-Sale",
  "transaction_type": "purchase",
  "method": "credit_card",
  "amount": "1299",
  "eci_indicator":"2",
  "currency_code": "USD",
  "credit_card": {
      "type": "visa",
      "cardholder_name": "John Smith",
      "card_number": "4788250000028291",
      "exp_date": "1020",
      "cvv": "123"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but  in website side integrated successfully.

Comment: @Rohit Then how is this managed in Wordpress plugin using this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-payeezy-pay/ ?

Comment: @Rohan - it depends on how the plugin operates. The plugin publisher should be able to help you with it.

Comment: @Rohit means that plugin is not provided by Payeezy. right?